# Выровнять фон ListView

Tags: android, listview

Задаю фон для ListView

```
  listView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.documents_delete);
```

Как можно выровнять картинку по центру фона в оригинальный размер и в принципе менять настройки фоновой картинки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас 2 варианта:

1. Создать `xml-drawable` в коем поместить картинку в тег `bitmap`. Так ей можно будет пару параметров задать, в т.ч. размещение по центру.
2. Не использоать фон, а свою разметку подложить под `ListView` (который с прозрачным фоном). В соей разметке можно всё что угодно сделать.

Comment: А можно еще забить на это дело вовсе, ибо списки имеют свойство растягиваться :) А картинки вроде все в этом случае принимают свойство уродливости :D

Comment: @Flippy, списки не должны растягиваться) Они должны иметь статическую высоту/ширину и лишь скролить контент в себе) Так что растяжений не должно быть при кошерном их использовании)

Comment: Точно, точно) Не подумал..